# How get values out of a callback? (NodeJs + Mongoose)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, callback

I'm not too good with callbacks, and now I have problems to find a document with mongoose but use the document in the same action/controller before send a response.

```
uploadFile = function(req,res) {
    var _objs = {};
    function retrieveUser(objs,username, callback) {
        User.findOne({ 'username': username })
            .exec(function(err, user){
                if(err) callback(err,null,null);
                else callback(null,user,objs);
            });
    }//retrieveUser()

    retrieveUser(_objs,req.body.user,function(err,user,_objs) {
        if(err) console.log('ERROR: ' + err);
        _objs.user = user;
        console.log(_objs.user);
    });

    console.log(_objs);
}
```

So, inside the callback function the `console.log()` shows the object rightly, but the second `console.log()` shows me `_objs` as empty. Well, I need to fill `_objs` with other objects as attributes, How can I acchieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Everything is working as designed. Your code will be executed as follows:

```
retrieveUser(_objs,req.body.user,function(err,user,_objs) {

    // will be executed when the retrieveUser function completes is tasks...

    if(err) console.log('ERROR: ' + err);
    _objs.user = user;
    console.log(_objs.user);
});

// ...meanwhile, execution will continue here.

console.log(_objs); // depending on how fast retrieveUser calls the callback, _objs will be set or (more likely) not set.
```

You can either continue the control flow of your application inside the callback or use frameworks like [Streamline.js](https://github.com/Sage/streamlinejs), [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async), [Step](https://github.com/creationix/step), [Seq](https://github.com/substack/node-seq), [IcedCoffeeScript](http://maxtaco.github.io/coffee-script/), [promise.js](https://github.com/stackp/promisejs), ...

Comment: Thanks!! I thought I was writing wrong. At really is some complex, I'm gonna use async.js, `series(tasks, [callback])` it seems to be what I need. I will repost what I'll do

Comment: If you want to use the result of a callback, try `waterfall(tasks, [callback])`, see https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is what I did. At really for what I expected that is something similar to what I do in controllers in others frameworks of others languages, query for some entities and create another one that will be related to the previous that was queried.

```
uploadPic = function(req, res, next) {
    var username = req.body.user,
        estId = req.body.est;

    async.series([
        function(callback) {
            User.findOne({ 'username': username})
                .exec(function(err, user){
                    if(err) return callback(err);

                    if(!user) return callback(new Error("No user whit username " + username + " found."));

                    callback(null,user);
                });
        },
        function(callback) {
            Est.findById(estId)
                .exec(function(err,est) {
                    if(err) return callback(err);

                    if(!est) return callback(new Error("No Est with ID " + estId + " found"));

                    callback(null,est);
                })
        },
    ],function(err,results){
        if(err) return next(err);

        console.log(results);

        /// do my own stuffs here!

    });// end async.series()

}
```